# Cannot deliver message to the Jarl of Whiterun

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have just joined the Imperial Legion, and General Tullius gave me a message to deliver to the Jarl. I have it in my inventory, and the quest marker is above the Jarl's head, however approaching him and talking gives no new or quest specific dialogue. How do I deliver the message? Please help

Comment: Make sure you complete the main Quest before doing Civil War quests!

Comment: So what was the answer, completing Dragon Rising or waiting, traveling, or reloading?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have not yet completed [Dragon Rising](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Dragon_Rising). It's part of the main quest after the quest Bleak Falls Barrow. The Jarl won't talk to you until you complete the quest and become Thane, then talk to the Jarl. If you already completed Dragon Rising, and you still can't get the Jarl to get the message, reload any save, wait, or fast travel to any place and back.